# What is the converse of $P \implies (Q \implies R)$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is the mathematical converse of $P \implies (Q \implies R)$

either

$(Q \implies R) \implies P$

or

$R \implies Q \implies P$

In other words, do I apply the converse for the nested sentence and then apply the converse to the outer sentence?

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the former. 
The converse of $P \implies (Q \implies R)$ is

$(Q \implies R) \implies P$.

Comment: Why don't I need to apply the converse to the inner statements?

Comment: @KurtMueller The converse of $P\implies S$ is $S\implies P$.  You do not change the $S$, which here is $(Q\implies R)$

Comment: @KurtMueller One of the main reasons to use the term converse is because, if an implication and it's converse are both true, then the condition and consequence of the implication are equivalent.  In other words, if you have $A \implies B$ and $B \implies A$, then you can infer $A \iff B$.  However, from $A \implies (B \implies C)$ and $C \implies (B \implies A)$ you cannot infer any sort of equivalence.

Answer (score 2):

The converse of a conditional sentence $A \implies B$ is $B \implies A$. Note that this definition applies only to sentences whose **main connective** is $\implies$, and it does not depend on any other connectives that appear in the sentence. So, to find the converse we can ignore any connectives besides the main $\implies$.

In your case, just let $(Q \implies R) =: A$. Then your sentence becomes $P \implies A$. The converse of this is $A \implies P$, which by the definition of A is $(Q \implies R) \implies P$.